# jQuery on click change outer element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have structure like this:

```
<div class="summary entry-summary">
  <form>
    <div class="single_variation_wrap">         
      <div class="single_variation">
        <span class="price">
           <span class="amount">200.00грн.</span>
        </span>
        <p class="stock out-of-stock">Нет в наличии</p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <ul class="variation-select" attr="pa_varnish_color"></ul>
  <ul class="variation-select" attr="pa_type_of_furniture"></ul>
</div>
```

I need on

```
click $(".variation-select").last().click(function () { })
```

change

```
  <p class="stock out-of-stock">Нет в наличии</p>
```

like this:

```
`$("p.stock").prependTo(".single_variation");`
```

- move p.stock to be first element of .single_variation. 
  I need to do this on click because first when page load there no .single_variation_wrap it's hidden. After click the last .variation-select .single_variation_wrap become to be visible.
  For better understand i load my page on hosting and adding link here. Also I add screenshot where I explain what I need to do.

page link: [Product page link](http://test.agamadigital.com/?p=18)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want to move the red text above the 200.00rph when you clcik that last button "Rcehb"?

Comment: You are right. When I click last .variation-select. There are many different variations can be. Red vs дуб, green vs клен and others.

Comment: I dont understand Russian, but do the "Tnn Aepeba" buttons all do something different? Can you assign a click function to each one or do you only want the last one?

Comment: First, i will get form with price only after click last variation. If you didn't click last variation - you will not get price form.That is problem, i can $("p.stock").prependTo(".single_variation"); do this only after click last variation. I don't have other way, or I don't know other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A delegated `click` event handler, attached to a non-changing ancestor, will do what you state, but I am not sure exactly what your aim is (not without more HTML and code):

```
 $(".summary").on("click", ".variation-select:last", function () { })
```

It works by applying the jQuery selector (`.variation-select:last`) at *event time* and not at *event registration time* (which is what `click()` does). Any `click` events bubble up to your `class="summary"` element, then the selector is applied to any elements in the bubble-chain, then your function is run against any matching elements that caused the event. In this case, your last `variation-select` element.

Comment: Yes!))) Many time I was trying to apply $(".variation-select").last().click(function () { }) but I was broke how to select outer element. Thank you. Next time I will now how to do this right way